# Can run java programs without an OS?

Tags: java, jvm

I know that all java programs are executed by the JVM. This makes java compatible with all operating systems (Write once, run anywhere). But can I run a java program *without* an OS? 
Maybe run just the JVM? And if it is possible, will the functionality be affected in any way?

Note: My main question is, can java programs be directly run on hardware (via a JVM)? Are there any low level JVMs that I could 'boot up' in my computer?

Comment: How can you run something without an OS?...

Comment: There was some company that had a board with a chip that ran Java code. Not sure if they still exist, it seemed a bit odd.

Comment: @JRSofty Azul still exists, and they still produce processors that are optimized for Java, but I believe there focus is now more on optimized JVM implementations.

Answer (score 7):

Factually we can have jvm without OS. 
Heard about some work in going in that direction.

> Gained with Oracle's acquisition of BEA Systems ... Oracle has
>   resuscitated avant-garde virtualization technology: a Java Virtual
>   Machine that runs directly on the hypervisor, without an operating
>   system.